# OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Tags: python, overflow

I want to find all the palindrome numbers between 10000 to 100000 but I am getting this error and I did read the solution to similar problems but wasn't satisfied

```
for i in range(10000, 100000):
    r=i
    s=0
    k=0
    while r>0:
        d=r%10
        s=(s+(d*(10**k)))
        k+=1
        r=r/10
    if s==i:
        a.append(i)
```

Comment: i believe that range of numbers takes too large for python to calculate with.
I might be wrong, if so, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You could try to use the helper function - `is_palindrome` to get the range you want faster.  -eg.  str(n)... compare with str(n)[::-1]

Comment: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem you should not need to floating-point numbers at all.

You probably didn't intend this, but accidentally used them by the line

```
r = r / 10
```

because this is the floating-point division operator.

To remove the last digit from a number, use integer division:

```
r = r // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10000, 100000)
boolean_selection = [str(i) == str(i)[::-1] for i in a]
res = a[boolean_selection]
```